# Handle Realm in kmm

Tags: kotlin, realm, kotlin-multiplatform

I don't know why app crashed

```
try {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        realm.writeBlocking {
            copyToRealm(Item().apply {
                summary = "Do the laundry"
                isComplete = false
            })
        }
    }
} catch (e:Exception){
    Log.d("ERROR_REALM", e.message?:"")
}
```

app crashed after app call `realm.writeBlocking` and don't go catch and don't can't see in console where the error

I need handle Realm package, but app crashed after call `realm.writeBlocking`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so, that should reveal the line the code is crashing on. Also, we don't know what `copyToRealm` does so that may need a second look.